# How to add a new user in DB2

Tags: db2, addition

How can I add a new user with password in **DB2** and grand him access to the database, to select,insert,update data ?
I need to do this from command line.

Comment: What platform?  It will make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike many other DBMSs, DB2 does not store users inside the database. Authentication is done either at the OS level, or through the use of authentication plugins.